# Filling formula to end of populated range

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I want to copy my formula down to the end of the row- but my syntax seems to be off.

```
Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("D3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[1]=""low"",""1"",""0"")&IF(RC[2]=""LOW"",""1"",""0"")&IF(RC[3]=""Negative"",""1"",""0"")"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Helper Column"
    Range("D3").Select
    **Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Selection.End(xlDown)**
```

Comment: and were magicians who sit inside your head and know exactly what your spreadsheet looks like and what you are expecting as an end result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the last row of the column and then in one go enter the formulas. For example (UNTESTED)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sFormula As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Change this to the relevant formula
    sFormula = "=Sum(A1:C1)"

    With ws
        '~~> Find Last Row of Col D
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Enter the formula
        .Range("D3:D" & lRow).Formula = sFormula
    End With
End Sub
```

**Note**: If Col B has the data which defines your last row then change `.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` to `.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Great, I'll test this approach. Essentially identify the last populated row in the column and assign it to a variable and then utilize that variable to define the range...